# How to get type of chan with reflect package

Tags: go, channel, reflect

Say I have a chan in Go:

```
var c = make(chan int)
```

how can discover that it's a channel using:

```
var isChannel = reflect.ValueOf(c).Kind() == reflect.Chan
```

but does anyone know how I determine the type of the channel, in this case `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Elem` to get the channel type:

```
var isChannel = reflect.ValueOf(c).Kind() == reflect.Chan
channelType := reflect.ValueOf(c).Type().Elem()
```

For an `int` channel, `channelType` will be `int`.

Comment: thanks, I am trying the same thing on a map too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243799/pring-the-key-value-types-of-a-golang-map