# Print the key/value types of a Golang map

Tags: go, reflection, reflect

I am trying to print the type of a map, eg: map[int]string

```
func handleMap(m reflect.Value) string {

    keys := m.MapKeys()
    n := len(keys)

    keyType := reflect.ValueOf(keys).Type().Elem().String()
    valType := m.Type().Elem().String()

    return fmt.Sprintf("map[%s]%s>", keyType, valType)
}
```

so if I do:

```
log.Println(handleMap(make(map[int]string)))
```

I want to get `"map[int]string"`

but I can't figure out the right calls to make.

Comment: Any reason why the simple `fmt.Printf("Type: %T\n", m)` is not sufficient? Try it out [here](https://play.golang.org/p/UxxAo-wukKo)!

Comment: yeah I think that should work, thanks! however, see the next comment

Comment: since I already have the value `x :=reflect.ValueOf(m)`, it would be nice if there were an api that could accept the Value x instead of the value m, if you follow

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean.. Is it [this](https://play.golang.org/p/ES8omWuA4bf)?.

Comment: You should aim to avoid reflection whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use `reflect`.  But if you must use `reflect`:

- A `reflect.Value` value has a `Type()` function, which returns a [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) value.
- If that type's `Kind()` is `reflect.Map`, that `reflect.Value` is a value of type `map[T1]T2` for some types T1 and T2, where T1 is the key type and T2 is the element type.

Therefore, when using `reflect`, we can pull apart the pieces like this:

```
func show(m reflect.Value) {
    t := m.Type()
    if t.Kind() != reflect.Map {
        panic("not a map")
    }
    kt := t.Key()
    et := t.Elem()
    fmt.Printf("m = map from %s to %s\n", kt, et)
}
```

[See a more complete example on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TYaz8-CjWAQ).  (Note that both maps are actually nil, so there are no keys and values to enumerate.)

Answer (score 2):

```
func handleMap(m interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%T", m)
}
```